# Powershell Replace text in text file not removing

Tags: arrays, powershell

Trying to remove a line in a text file using the below but nothing is moving, however if i find in the document for example 'a' and replace with 'b' it works?! what am i doing wrong here? thanks!

so basically when a number is used like below, it removes the line totally. tried $null and "$number","" and no luck.

```
    (Get-Content C:\temp\Test.txt) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "tel:+123456789;ext=1234","$null"} | 
Set-Content C:\temp\Test.txt
```

Comment: You have an output line for every input line. That can never result in fewer lines. You need an `if () { }` inside the loop to decide whether to emit an output line (or not, and drop it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will remove the text from the file.

```
$path = "C:\temp\Test.txt"
$remove = "tel:+123456789;ext=1234"

$content = Get-Content $path
$newContent = ($content | ForEach-Object { $_.Replace($remove, "") })
Set-Content $path $newContent
```

If I wanted to remove an entire line that had that number in it:

```
$newContent = ($content | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -like "*$remove*") { return "" } else { return $_ } })
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to remove all lines that match a regex from a file:

```
@(Get-Content C:\temp\Test.txt) -notmatch 'tel:+123456789;ext=1234' |
  Set-Content C:\temp\Test.txt
```

- With an array as the LHS, operator `-notmatch` acts as a *filter* that passes (only) non-matching lines through.
- Note that replacing a file in this manner is brittle in that data loss can occur if something goes wrong while writing back to the file.
- By not specifying `-Encoding`, `Set-Content` uses the `Default` encoding, which is the system's active "ANSI" legacy code page.